# Tensorboard Expand Node Glitch

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I keep unexpectedly running into some kind of weird glitch where Tensorboard fails to expand a node in the graph. When I hit the plus button (in the top right of the node) the node doesn't expand. Instead, the name of the node gets slightly larger. Hitting the minus sign reverses the effect.

Has anyone run into this before? If so, how and or why does it happen?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by upgrading Tensorflow from 1.1 to 1.4.